# How to apply custom font in fabric text object?

Tags: javascript, text, fabricjs

I would like to use custom font in fabric text object, I followed the link below:
http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/

But it seems that it's only supported in node.js.

Is there any way to support it on simple fabric text object on canvas?

Comment: Include custom font in a document, using CSS, just like you would do to render it in HTML. Then specify font family for `fabric.Text` instance.

Comment: HI @kangax.. i working in Curved text using fabric.js how can i used font family for curve text....? any predefined property for font family?

Answer (score 14):

Use
CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'),
url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

Create fabric text object instance :

```
 var object = new fabric.Text("NEW TEXT", { 
    fontFamily: "myFirstFont", 
    left: 150,
    top: 100,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "left",
    fill: "#000000"
});
canvas.add(object);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Simple Css property Font **@Face**