# Load custom font for Fabric.js

Tags: fonts, fabricjs

I'm looking to add an Open-Type Font to my Fabric.js app. I found this question, [Custom font in Pixi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002850/custom-font-in-pixi-js), pretty much asking the same thing. How can we load a font from our file system? I tried using CSS @font-face as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894842/how-to-apply-custom-font-in-fabric-text-object) and the one linked above. It seems I had some spelling issues with my code in relation to my filename. So to be clear, the correct answer is to use CSS font face like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: test-family;
    src: url('path/to/fontfile');
}
```

Then use the font family name inside the text object as such:

```
var t = new fabric.Text('text', {
    fontFamily: 'test-family',
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. But why does it take too long to load the font?